# Python - out of memory when reading an xmlfile opened with urllib2

Tags: python, urllib2

I have a python program which gathers affiliate product feeds and saves these as an xml file. Some of those product feeds are really big which results in an out of memory error. This is my code where it happens:

```
xmlfile = urllib2.urlopen(feed.URL)
log.info("Opened the file")
contents = xmlfile.read()
log.info("Read the file")
xmlfile.close()
```

"Opened the file" is the last thing to get logged, so reading the file is what's taking so much memory.  I can't do anything about the file size. Also, I run Python 2.7.8 64 bit. That means I'm able to use 4 GB of RAM right? The file size is 450mb, there are no other threads running, no open files. How can it even take this much memory?

Comment: Watch out for malicious XML (https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.html#xml-vulnerabilities)

Comment: @ChirilaAlexandru - but so far its just a read, no xml parsing.

Comment: I tried a 4.5 gig file and saw memory usage spike at 12Gig (on linux, via top) before settling down when the string was fully constructed. Looks like intermediate buffering is a killer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I wanted is not to parse the file but to save it directly. This did the trick:

```
import urllib

testfile = urllib.URLopener()
testfile.retrieve("http://randomsite.com/file.gz", "file.gz")
```

Answer (score 3):

Instead of reading the entire XML document into memory before parsing, stream it from the web, and parse pieces as they come in.  Doc: https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.iterparse

Thanks to @tdelaney for the clarification.

### source

```
import urllib
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

URL = 'http://www.w3schools.com/xml/note.xml'
for event,elem in ET.iterparse( urllib.urlopen(URL) ):
    print event, elem.__dict__
```

### output

```
end {'text': 'Tove', 'attrib': {}, 'tag': 'to', 'tail': '\n\t', '_children': []}
end {'text': 'Jani', 'attrib': {}, 'tag': 'from', 'tail': '\n\t', '_children': []}
end {'text': 'Reminder', 'attrib': {}, 'tag': 'heading', 'tail': '\n\t', '_children': []}
end {'text': "Don't forget me this weekend!", 'attrib': {}, 'tag': 'body', 'tail': '\n', '_children': []}
end {'text': '\n\t', 'attrib': {}, 'tag': 'note', '_children': [<Element 'to' at 0x1968a10>, <Element 'from' at 0x1968a50>, <Element 'heading' at 0x1968b10>, <Element 'body' at 0x1968bd0>]}
```

Comment: Writing to disk first is a great idea, but if the OP just wants to parse the feed, `ET.iterparse(urllib2.urlopen(feed.URL))` would work as well.

Comment: a great point @tdelaney, I've updated the code, including a real URL and output.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I don't exactly get it. How do I save this output to a XML file?

Comment: Just to be clear: I don't want to PARSE the data. I just want to save the xml files exactly as they are downloaded.